# Google Analytics Cross Domain E-Commerce Campaign Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I want to track  e-Commerce related stuff with Google Analytics in relation to campaigns.

The basket/checkout (included via iframe) is on a different domain  than the shop. 
I've enabled e-commerce tracking in GA, added tracking scripts to both pages and I get a lot of data but it seems that the campaign information gets lost, because all e-commerce data has only "shop.com / referral" as source/medium and not "campaign1/newsletter" as I would expect.

Example:

Script on shop.com:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxx']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'shop.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
...
```

Enter the site via

```
http://shop.com/page.html?utm_campaign=campaign1&utm_source=newsletter...
```

Get iframe src

```
 via _gat._getTrackerByName()._getLinkerUrl('http://basket.com/page.html')
```

which returns something like

```
http://basket.com/page.html?__utma=14776951xxx&__utmb=14776xx..
```

Embed iframe with this url..

On basket.com/page.html I've added the following GA E-Commerce tracking code

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxx']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'basket.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
 '1234',           // transaction ID - required
 'Name',
 '123.4' .....
_gaq.push(['_addItem', ...
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);..
```

The really strange thing is, that even the tracking pixel (which is loaded in the iframe to track e-commerce events) seems to be correct

```
http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.4dc&....%3Futm_source%3Dnewsletter2%26utm_campaign%3Dcampaign1...
```

Did i miss something?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the _getLinkerUrl() method to pass the cookies data to the iframe.

```
_gaq.push(function() {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
    iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://www.my-example-iframecontent.com/');
});
```

You can find full details here --> [Tracking Across iFrames](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#trackingIFrames)
... and here --> [Tracking Across Multiple Domains and Sub-domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains)

Hope it helps.